# Find final world coordinates from model matrix or quaternion

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, rotation, quaternions

I am displaying an object in OpenGL using a model matrix for the object, which I build from my pre-stored object location AND a quaternion applied to the rotation. I need to find the final cartesian coordinates **in 3D** of my object AFTER the rotations and transformations applied (the coordinates that the object appears at on the screen). How can I get the plain coordinates?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking... multiply the matrix with the point coordinate vector? However, if you want to get the position on the screen, you also need to take into account the camera matrix.

Comment: @cooky451: The view matrix is only one piece, there's also the projection matrix (which must not be confused with a camera!) and the normalization step.

Comment: i am trying to get the world coordinates of an object, with the rotations applied (the final position). i am NOT rotating the object at origin, so the object has some offset due to rotation at a non-origin position. I need to find that position that I see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have an object; if you rendered it without applying any transformation, its center would be at **[0,0,0]**.

You have a point, **[a,b,c]**, in 3D space.  You apply a translation to the modelview matrix.  Now, if you rendered the object, its center would be at **[a,b,c]** in world space coordinates.

You have a quaternion, **[qw,qx,qy,qz]**.  You [create a rotation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation#Conversion_to_and_from_the_matrix_representation), **M**, from this and apply it to the modelview matrix.  Now you want to know the new coordinates, **[a',b',c']**, of the object's center in world space.

If this is true, then the easiest way is to just do the matrix multiplication yourself:

```
a' = m11*a + m12*b + m13*c
b' = m21*a + m22*b + m23*c
c' = m31*a + m32*b + m33*c
```

where

```
    [m11 m12 m13]
M = [m21 m22 m23]
    [m31 m32 m33]
```

But perhaps you're not actually building **M**.  Another way would be to use the quaternion directly, although that essentially involves building the rotation matrix and then using it.

There should be no need to actually use `gluProject`.  When you apply the rotation to the modelview matrix, the matrix multiply is done there.  So you could just get the values from the matrix itself:

```
double mv[16];
glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX,mv);
a' = mv[13];
b' = mv[14];
c' = mv[15];
```

This tells you where the modelview matrix is moving the model's origin.

Comment: I did implement the method in a similar fashion, but this seems even simpler. Great answer, I'm sure I'll be using your method in my future projects which are coming very soon :)

Comment: Thanks, this helped me out.  FYI, glGetDoublev should have a lowercase v.  I'd edit your response to change it myself but I don't seem to be allowed to make a single-character edit.

Answer (score 1):

Re-implement [`gluProject()`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/gluProject.xml) and apply everything but the viewport transform.

Comment: wouldn't it be a bit overkill? i am not very good with matrices and projection, it should be the last choice, if there is a simpler method? or if the gluProject IS simple, where can I find a simple explanation of it (the ones i've found are confusing)

Comment: or does pushing the current matrices, loading identity as view matrix and loading my model matrix as modelview matrix, and calling gluProject work?