# Getting a vector coordinate post matrix multiplication

Tags: math, graphics, 3d, opengl-es-2.0, transformation

I have a series of transformations that take my object and put it somewhere else. I am manually multiplying these transformations for the programmable pipeline in GL/ES. I'm rotating around distant arbitrary points and also translating, and while I have no trouble getting my object to finally position where I want it, I'd like to know **how I can extract the final 3D vector coordinate of its position after these transformations.**?

One option, suggested by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9912357/find-final-world-coordinates-from-model-matrix-or-quaternion), is to simply multiply your starting position by the final matrix and keep that result vector as the final coordinate. If so, what is the vector I use to represent my object's origin before these transformations? Because multiplying a matrix by my origin (0,0,0) simply results in a vector of zeroes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is surprisingly simple.

If I have a matrix `M` that is the final transformation created by all the matrix multiplications, then I can find the center of an object transformed by `M` by simply:

```
M * vector(0,0,0,1) // creates a 4D vector, where the first three, x,y,z are the coordinates
```

This is easily [done manually](http://www.facstaff.bucknell.edu/mastascu/elessonsHTML/Circuit/MatVecMultiply.htm) in the code.

The key piece the question was missing was the exact vector to use for this multiplication.

Comment: right! thanks for pointing that out. or, if using row-vectors and row-major orientation, the 4th row of the matrix.